# Regex for hex color codes in bbcode?

Tags: java, android, regex, bbcode

I am currently trying to test the regex pattern matching the following:

```
[#123456]

[#aabc36]
```

And then convert to HTML codes:

```
<FONT COLOR="#123456">
```

But if pattern like:

```
[/#123456]
```

then to be replaced as

```
</FONT>
```

I have tried the following pattern:

```
\\[#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}\\]|\\[[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}\\]
```

but it fails.

And what I want to is to get the extracted color hex code to the HTML font color for replacement.

The below is my method for regex replacement:

```java
public String replaceColor(String text  , String imageLocation ){

    StringBuffer imageBuffer = new StringBuffer (""); 

    String bbcode = "\\[#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}\\]|\\[[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}\\]";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(bbcode));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    //populate the replacements map ...
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {

        //String orginal = replacements.get(matcher.group(1));
        imageBuffer.append("<FONT COLOR=\"#123456\">");
        String replacement = imageBuffer.toString();
        builder.append(text.substring(i, matcher.start()));

        if (replacement == null) {
            builder.append(matcher.group(0));
        } else {
            builder.append(replacement);
        }
        i = matcher.end();
    }

    builder.append(text.substring(i, text.length()));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Remove `Pattern.quote`, that's escaping all the regex metacharacters in `bbcode`.

Comment: how to extract the bbcode words between [  ]   anyway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
    s = s.replaceAll("\\[#(\\w{6}|\\w{3})]", "<FONT COLOR=\"#$1>\">")
             .replaceAll("\\[/#(\\w{6}|\\w{3})]", "</FONT>");
```

Comment: Looks good, but you're not accounting for three-digit, compressed values like `#123`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `Pattern.quote` call, which is making your regex match all literal characters.  If you want to capture part of the match, you need use a match group `()`.  To simplify it, change your expression to this:

```
String bbcode = "\\[(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}([A-Fa-f0-9]{3})?)\\]";
```

And use `matcher.group(1)` to reference the part between the square brackets.

Comment: Nice regex, but you shouldn't have to use `group(1)` directly.  Just do a `replaceAll()` like in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20985753/20938), using `$1` to plug the hex value back in.